# React Redux router error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying setup a Redux + React Router app. I think the problem is with ImmutableJS, but I do not understand how to resolve it.

**client.js**

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import React from 'react'
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { match, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

function createSelectLocationState(reducerName) {
  let prevRoutingState;
  let prevRoutingStateJS;

  return (state) => {
    const routingState = state.get(reducerName); // or state.routing

    if (!routingState.equals(prevRoutingState)) {
      prevRoutingState = routingState;
      prevRoutingStateJS = routingState.toJS();
    }

    return prevRoutingStateJS;
  };
}

function configureStore(history, initialState) {
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    routing: routerReducer
  });

  return createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history)
      )
    )
  );
}

const initialState = fromJS(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);
const store = configureStore(browserHistory, initialState);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: createSelectLocationState('routing')
});
const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');

const renderApp = () => {
  const routes = require('./routes');

  match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    render(
      <AppContainer>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router {...renderProps} />
        </Provider>
      </AppContainer>,
      rootNode
    );
  });
};

// Enable hot reload by react-hot-loader
if (module.hot) {
  const reRenderApp = () => {
    try {
      renderApp();
    } catch (error) {
      const RedBox = require('redbox-react').default;

      render(<RedBox error={error} />, rootNode);
    }
  };

  module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      // Preventing the hot reloading error from react-router
      unmountComponentAtNode(rootNode);
      reRenderApp();
    });
  });
}

renderApp();
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: state.get is not a function

[image]

In `state` this object

[image]

I use `"react": "^15.3.2"`, `"redux": "^3.6.0"`, `"react-router": "^3.0.0"`

**UPDATE 1**
I now use `combineReducers` from `redux-immutable`:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable'
```

But get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: routingState.equals is not a function

[image]

Here:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I fixed hereinabove issue, but there one more error

[image]

All code i posted in [this](https://github.com/perevezencev/react-easy-start) repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stays at `src/index.js` file with the `require` statement of route.js.

When you `require` `es6` module which has `default`, you have to use the default from `require`d module. Something like,

```
const routes = require('./routes').default;
```

This fixed your issues without any other change on your git repo.

Answer (score 0):

The `combineReducers` you are using is not using `immutable`. Each branch is `immutable` by setting `fromJS(blah)` but not on the highest level of your state. Use `redux-immutable` instead:

`import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable';`

Comment: Yes, problem is solved, but not error 
Uncaught TypeError: routingState.equals is not a function(…)

Comment: You either not creating history or you are not passing history down to your router.

Comment: I don't understand, how it should look like in my code?